# How to do cross-validation on random forest?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, prediction

I am working on a binary classification using random forest. My dataset is imbalanced with 77:23 ratio. my dataset shape is (977, 7)

I initially tried the below

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced',max_depth=5,max_features='sqrt',n_estimators=300,random_state=24)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = mode.predict(X_test)
```

However, now I want to apply cross validation during my random forest training and then use that model to predict the y values for test data. So, I did the below

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced',max_depth=5,max_features='sqrt',n_estimators=300,random_state=24)
scores = cross_val_score(model,X_train, y_train,cv=10, scoring='f1')
y_pred = cross_val_predict(model,X_test,cv=10)
```

As you can see that this is incorrect. How can I apply cross-validation during training random forest and later, use that cross-validated model to predict `y_pred` correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The purpose of cross-validation is model checking, not model building.**

Once you have checked with cross-validation that you obtain similar metrics for every split, you have to train your model with **all** your training data.

Comment: Serra - upvoted for the help. So, we can fit our model only on `X_train`. Isn't there nothing like applying CV to your model DURING traiining?

Comment: We do like how I have done in my post (initial step) and later just do some cross_val_score to see whether my model results are not highly varyiant. If yes, I can consider that model is stable? and move onto predict function (like I have shown in my initial step)? Is that how it works?

Comment: So, we can;t predict anything using cross-validated model. because there is nothing like cross_validated model. When we mean, a model is cross-validated, it just means that we verified our model on different subsets of the train data and get an idea of average performance...

Comment: Yes, you are right (both comments above are correct). In fact, inside Random Forest, you are using a kind of CV, because you are generating different trees coming from different data.

Comment: Can I check with you on this related post? for train test split? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569295/rule-based-label-random-split-vs-time-based-split

Answer (score 1):

You can't use 'cross_val_score' or 'cross_val_predict' to get back a model post-cross-validation. Otherwise, you can use the code block below, to calculate the F1 score at each fold using the testing data and validation data.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

k = 10
kf_10 = KFold(n_splits = k, random_state = 24)
model_rfc = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced',max_depth=5,max_features='sqrt',n_estimators=300,random_state=24)
rfc_f1_CV_list = []
rfc_f1_test_list = []

for train_index, test_index in kf_10.split(X_train):
    X_train_CV, X_test_CV = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train_CV, y_test_CV = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    model_rfc.fit(X_train_CV, y_train_CV)

    #Target prediction & F1 score using the 10 rows left out from CV.
    y_pred_CV = model_rfc.predict(X_test_CV)
    rfc_f1_CV = f1_score(y_test_CV, y_pred_CV)
    rfc_f1_CV_list.append(rfc_f1_CV)

    #Target prediction & F1 score using the rows from your test split.
    y_pred_test = model_rfc.predict(X_test)
    rfc_f1_test = f1_score(y_test, y_pred_test)
    rfc_f1_test_list.append(rfc_f1_test)
```

You can modify the above code to save the model at a given fold and use it in the snippet below:

```
y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X_test, y_test, cv=10, scoring='f1') 
f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='binary')
```